# Jquery image bookmarklet not working in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Im working through Django By Example and in one chapter a Jquery bookmarklet is built within a Django app so that a user can easily save jpg images from a website into their user profile area within the Django app.

Im not an experienced JS or Jquery programmer but I did some JS some years back and can read the code however the tutorial does give exact instructions on what to do which I have followed and although I have managed to get the bookmarklet button to appear in my bookmarks bar in Chrome, nothing happens when I click it when browsing a webpage with jpg images.

This is my local Django dashboard where the bookmarklet button is added to the bookmarks bar and this part works fine

[image]

and this is what it should look like when clicked on, this is the part where nothing happens for me

[image]

these are the relevant js files

https://github.com/davejonesbkk/bookmarks/blob/master/images/templates/bookmarklet_launcher.js

https://github.com/davejonesbkk/bookmarks/blob/master/images/static/js/bookmarklet.js

the only thing I can see that is different with these compared to the files that came with the book is the indentation is a bit off but for some reason the indentation does seem to have changed a bit when I uploaded to Git and they dont look like that locally. Is indentation important in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the same book with the same examples but didn't had any trouble. Make sure your dashboard.html file is referring to the correct javascript file. If nothing works try to add the bookmark manually, you can see how that's done over here http://www.howtogeek.com/189358/beginner-geek-how-to-use-bookmarklets-on-any-device/ it'll sure to work.
And answer to your last question, Indentation is not as important in JavaScript as it's in Python, as python doesn't use any curly braces "{}" or semi-colons ";". But you can write your entire javascript code in a single line and it'll work because your using curly braces everywhere to tell which line of code ends where.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the above. In addition, the following:

1. Error I noticed in the book:

In `bookmarklet-launcher.js` the js function being called from `bookmarklet.js` is called `myBookmarklet()`, however there is no function called this way in `bookmarklet.js`. So, you may want to use the same name in both js files.
Practically speaking however, the bookmarklet will always work because, not finding a `myBookmarklet` function in memory, `bookmarklet-launcher.js` appends the `bookmarklet.js` script to the body element and, being `bookmarklet.js` a self-invoking function, its content executed (without the need it to being called). There are some additional interesting technicalities here (the key function in `bookmarklet.js` is not self invoking but it will anyway be always called because of the script checking whether jQuery is present...) but ok, this is more relevant for those busy with the mentioned book ([Django 2 by example](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/django-2-example)).

2. Check whether bookmarkled, once you click on it, is added to the
   current webpage:

2.1. Open devtools (F12 on Chrome) and check e.g. in the html head element whether you find the newly added link element containing the css attribute and/or in the body element whether you find the script element containing the reference to the bookmarklet.js file.

2.2. Alternative: Add an alert message on top of the bookmarklet.js script so that it will be launched if it is correctly loaded. Example:

```
(function(){
    alert('bookmarkled loaded!');
    var jquery_version =...
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the error at number 1. I searched the entire chapter for the definition of `myBookmarklet` function but didn't find it anywhere. Now I'm sure it's a typo there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're trying to use it on a HTTP site only. Since you're serving from same protocol. HTTPS site would always tell say: There is a problem loadingbyour jquery. That's how I solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

dude.I have solved the problems I met like you.

The most important thing is that noticing the syntax error(without warnings),mainly caused by ignoring blank.
for example, in the line:

```
 jQuery('#bookmarklet .images').append('<a href="#"><img src="'+image_url+'"/></a>');
```

between `#bookmarklet` and `.images` should lie a blank space,because of jquery syntax rules(meaning to search tag with id of `bookmarklet` and search tag with class equaling `images` within result previously).

Another two places worth notice are codes containing `#bookmarklet .images a` and `#bookmarklet #close`,requiring blank spaces between filter condition.

That's where I found I made mistaks mainly after studying syntax of jquery.

You'd better compare your codes with codes already loaded up to github by someone to make sure there are no more little errors(such as spelling).